# Rig veda 1.35.1 and 7.35.10

Tags: vedas

[image: IIT kharagpur calendar] The above picture is screenshot of IIT kharagpur calendar 2022 . Here they say that Rig veda 1.35.1 and 7.35.10 talks about cosmic field , however I looked up many translations and none talks such things. Did sayana wrote about this in his commentary or is there a different verse in Rig veda talking unity of cosmic field as time and pillar (maybe IIT kharagpur made typo error) or no such verse exists ?